# ANTLR AST rules fail with RewriteEmptyStreamException

Tags: parsing, antlr

I have a simple grammar:

```
grammar sample;
options { output = AST; }
assignment
    : IDENT ':=' expr ';'
    ;
expr    
    : factor ('*' factor)*
    ;
factor
    : primary ('+' primary)*
    ;
primary
    : NUM
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;
IDENT : ('a'..'z')+ ;
NUM   : ('0'..'9')+ ;
WS    : (' '|'\n'|'\t'|'\r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

Now I want to add some rewrite rules to generate an AST. From what I've read online and in the Language Patterns book, I should be able to modify the grammar like this:

```
assignment
    : IDENT ':=' expr ';'   -> ^(':=' IDENT expr)
    ;
expr    
    : factor ('*' factor)* -> ^('*' factor+)
    ;
factor  
    : primary ('+' primary)* -> ^('+' primary+)
    ;
primary
    : NUM
    | '(' expr ')' -> ^(expr)
    ;
```

But it does not work. Although it compiles fine, when I run the parser I get a RewriteEmptyStreamException error. Here's where things get weird.

If I define the pseudo tokens ADD and MULT and use them instead of the tree node literals, it works without error.

```
tokens { ADD; MULT; }

expr    
    : factor ('*' factor)* -> ^(MULT factor+)
    ;
factor  
    : primary ('+' primary)* -> ^(ADD primary+)
    ;
```

Alternatively, if I use the node suffix notation, it also appears to work fine:

```
expr    
    : factor ('*'^ factor)*
    ;
factor  
    : primary ('+'^ primary)*
    ;
```

Is this discrepancy in behavior a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not a bug, AFAIK. Take your `expr` rule for example:

```
expr    
    : factor ('*' factor)* -> ^('*' factor+)
    ;
```

since the `*` might not be present, it should also not be in your AST rewrite rule. So, the above is incorrect and ANTLR complaining about it *is* correct.

Now if you insert an imaginary token like `MULT` instead:

```
expr    
    : factor ('*' factor)* -> ^(MULT factor+)
    ;
```

all is okay since your rule will always produce one or more `factor`'s.

What you probably meant to do is something like this:

```
expr    
    :  (factor -> factor) ('*' f=factor -> ^('*' $expr $f))*
    ;
```

Also see *chapter 7: Tree Construction* from [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference). Especially the paragraphs **Rewrite Rules in Subrules** (page 173) and **Referencing Previous Rule ASTs in Rewrite Rules** (page 174/175).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to generate an N-ary tree for the '*' operator with all children at the same level you can do this:

```
expr
    : (s=factor -> factor) (('*' factor)+ -> ^('*' $s factor+))?
    ;
```

Here are some examples of what this will return:

```
Tokens: AST
factor: factor
factor '*' factor: ^('*' factor factor)
factor '*' factor '*' factor: ^('*' factor factor factor)
```

Bart's third example above will produce a nested tree, since the result of $expr for each successive iteration is a node with two children, like this:

```
factor * factor * factor: ^('*' factor ^('*' factor factor))
```

which you probably don't need since multiplication is commutative.

Comment: Thanks a ton @JoelPM. This is exactly what I was looking for. We had an issue with deeply nested tree and stack overflows while evaluating. This gives us chance to generate an N-ary tree and drastically reduces the depth of tree